# Can't see Urbanairship push Notifications in Notification bar

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

My Android application using Urbaairship to receive push messages from server, I have added recent Urbanairaship lib. jar stable release 4.0.2. I have added all the code according to Urbanairship doc for integration it worked fine for newly created sample Project, but not working in my existing project. I have obtained projectId from google console and API key too & added it to Urbanairship application setting. Added development keys to airship.config file located in assets folder.

Problem is I'm not able to see coming notifications in Notification bar of my device, but I can see the notification logged in my logCat.

Guys I did lot of research cases are:

```
1) It shows notification with/without IntentReceiver in SampleApplication I created.
2) It shows notification without IntentReceiver even using custom Notifications builder in SampleApplication I created.
3) It won't show any notification until i create custom notification in my Projects Application class before registering IntentRevceiver.
```

Thank in advance.
Any Help will get appreciation.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 with Android 4.04 only. Do you have it on all devices you are working with?

Comment: yes I have it on all devices I'm working on.

Comment: Follow the docs: http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/android.html#android-getting-started-with-push

Answer (score 2):

Finally not getting any answers I'm looking for. So, I diagnosed issue myself and came across picture that Urbaairship not rendering the push it receives in IntentReceiver because some how it's not considering these push messages of It's own.

We can send push messages using urbanairship as well as from other platforms such as SNS  Amazon. When we receive messages from these other plat forms urbaairship won't render it because(It has some kind o identifier in message which differentiate It's messages from other push messages) It knows that received message belong to It or not, If it doesn't belong to it won't render it and show them in default format for push receive.

From Above scenario what I concluded is some how urbanairhip not considering my messages from urbanairship of It's own, some problem with application created on google console or urbanairship... trying to fix it.

The work around I found is to create custom Push notifications using CustomPushNotificationBuilder in Application class right after urbanairship takeoff.

```
CustomPushNotificationBuilder nb = new CustomPushNotificationBuilder();

                nb.statusBarIconDrawableId = R.drawable.app_icon_notification;//custom status bar icon

                nb.layout = R.layout.notification;
                nb.layoutIconDrawableId = R.drawable.app_icon_notification;//custom layout icon
                nb.layoutIconId = R.id.icon;
                nb.layoutSubjectId = R.id.subject;
                nb.layoutMessageId = R.id.message;

                // customize the sound played when a push is received
                nb.soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+this.getPackageName()+"/" +R.raw.cat);

                PushManager.shared().setNotificationBuilder(nb);
```

Hope this Helps you to work in right direction..

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the [custom handling of Push events?](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/android_features.html#android-push-events)

You need to:

- First, create a broadcast receiver for handling PushManager.ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED , PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED , and PushManager.ACTION_REGISTRATION_FINISHED:
- Add the receiver to the manifest
- Register the receiver in your application’s onCreate method after takeOff:

In the receiver you create, you need to display a notification

Comment: Thanks for your reply I did all these steps, thats why I'm able to receive push and are getting logged in my Eclipse Logcat.It working on sample project I created but not in my project no idea not even a single error/ warning in Logcat.